# Closing. Yes - that's it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I love the idea of MVVM but really struggling with the hoop-jumping required for *really* basic things like getting a value back from a modal dialog or closing a window.  I mean...

`App.xaml` defines `StartupUri=MainWindow.xaml`.

`MainWindow.xaml` defines `DataContext=MainWindowViewModel`.

As per MVVM, View knows about ViewModel but NOT vice versa.

I can't find a (common? logical? straightforward?) way of intercepting the close event.  I can use "clever" code blocks like MVVMLight .. but I always end up with either handling an event (messily) or not being able to cancel the close or missing it completely.

I refuse to believe this is so difficult - it must be me falling into another noobie pitfall.  Please put me straight!

Thank you again for your time and patience - it is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily handled via attached properties or a Behavior.  I wrote a [sample on the Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/WindowCloseBehavior/) showing how you can use a Behavior to wire this handling up to a command in your VM without using code behind.

Comment: Ahhhhhh kinda seeing the outline of trees in the woods...  Thanks again, I'll let you know how I go!

Answer (score 0):

[Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) framework handles dialogs and closing windows very elegantly in my opinion